# Create Copy of Excel Workbook and Remove Query Connections

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

Evening Everyone,

I have a workbook that has power query connections and I'm looking to create and save a copy of that file and remove the query connections in the new file and keep the connections in the first file.

This is the code so far which I've combined from the web:

```
Clone Copy()
Dim cn As WorkbookConnection
Dim qr As WorkbookQuery
Dim NewFilePath As String

    NewFilePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Cloned_Workbook.xlsm"

    If VBA.Dir(NewFilePath) <> "" Then
        MsgBox "File With Same Name Exists already. Enter Different Name"
        End
    End If

    With ActiveWorkbook
        .SaveCopyAs Filename:=NewFilePath
        On Error Resume Next
        For Each cn In ThisWorkbook.Connections
    cn.Delete
Next
For Each qr In ThisWorkbook.Queries
    qr.Delete
    Next
End Sub
```

This removes the query connections from the existing file and keeps the connections in the copied file which is the opposite of what I'm looking for.

Any help is much appreciated :)

Shrew

Comment: Don't use `ThisWorkbook`, that refers to the workbook the code is run from.  Try `For each cn in Workbooks(newFilePath).Connections`

Comment: To add to @BruceWayne's comment - you need to open the copy you just created before you can remove the connections from it.

Comment: Thank you @BruceWayne - I changed 'ThisWorkbook' to Workbooks and the connections in the original document remained so thank you for that. Tim, you're right it didn't remove the connections in the new copy. Do you know of any way of removing the connections without having to open the new document? Many Thanks :)